# Send a change to a new branch

Tags: git, pycharm

Is there a way to send individual lines of code from the current branch to the stash of another branch or to it's unstaged changes list without breaking my current workflow? The effect I want to have is that whenever I have an idea I can make a #TODO comment and then with a shortkey send it to one of the existing branches or to a new branch that is comming from the current checked out branch.

Comment: The stash is shared accross branches, you can',t attach some stash entry to a specific branch. That being said, it might be enough to give your stash a useful name (`-m <message>`) to find it back later and apply it from your branch.

Comment: Stash has a `-p` option that would allow you to select individually what you would like to stash (I suppose... from what I know from `git add -p` ). Check `git help stash`.

Answer (score 0):

Summary: use `git worktree` instead.

Whether you're new to Git, or an experienced Git user, I recommend *avoiding* `git stash`.  The reason is simple:

- `git stash` works by making *commits*.
- `git commit` *also* works by making commits.

What's special about `git stash`—well, the *first* thing that's special—is that the commits it makes are on *no branch*.  (Commits, in Git, do not have to be on any branch, and any one particular commit can be on *many* branches at the same time, so there's no actual need for branches in a Git repository.  We—humans—use branch names because Git's names for individual commits are those big ugly random-looking hash IDs, which we're *bad* at.  Quick: are `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5296ca2a323adbbc5` and `c3ff4cec66ec004d884507f5276ca2a323adbbc5` the same, or different?  How about `main` vs `feature`, are those the same, or different?<sup>1</sup>)

The other things that are special about the commits made by `git stash` are:

- they're on *no branch*, so they're easy to move from branch to branch;
- they're on *no branch*, so they're terribly difficult to *find* and keep straight;
- they come in "stash clumps" or as what I sometimes like to call a "stash bag", which means that only the `git stash` command can deal with them correctly;
- the rest of Git will treat a stash commit *as if* it were a *merge* commit, because technically, the commit named by a stash ref *is* a merge commit, except that it won't work right when treated as a merge commit, which means no other Git command works right with them.

One of these is a good thing: a stash is easy to "move" from branch to branch.  The rest are very bad, no good, horrible, terrible things.  If you run `git show stash` instead of `git stash show` by mistake, for instance, you often see *nothing*.  Git quietly pretends that you have an empty stash, even if you don't.

So that's why you should *avoid* `git stash`.  Just don't use it!

If you *must* use it, however, remember: `git stash` works by making *commits*, and then—having made a commit to save the state of your working tree—it runs `git reset --hard` to wipe out all your work.  That work is safely saved in the stash commits, but only `git stash` can get it back now.

It *is* possible to use `git stash -p`, as [eftshift0 notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0).  But there's a much better way, if your Git is at least 2.15 or so (2.17 or later is best): it's called `git worktree`.<sup>2</sup>

Using `git worktree add`, you can create a *second, separate working tree* that is on some other branch.  Suppose you're on a new branch you made, `feature/thingy`, and you're editing file `routines.py` and realize you should do something in a different existing or new branch.  Simply run:

```
git worktree add -b feature/new-feature ../new-feature main
```

to create a new working tree in `../new-feature` on a new branch `feature/new-feature` that springs from existing branch `main`.  Then you can start up a new Terminal window and `cd ../new-feature` and work in that Terminal session on the other branch, while leaving the current Terminal session alone so that you can continue working on `feature/thingy`.

(Whether Pycharm or any other IDE can handle `git worktree` is a separate question.  I generally avoid IDEs as they tend to be great at *one* thing and *terrible* at everything else, and I like to have a lot of good tools available at all times.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Perhaps a bit fairer: how about `main` vs `maim`, or `main` vs `marn`?

<sup>2</sup>The `git worktree` command was introduced in Git 2.5, but had a particularly nasty little bug in it until Git 2.15.  Some lesser bugs were fixed a few releases later as well, which is why I recommend 2.17 as a minimum here.